# webpack not generating css from less files

Tags: webpack, npm-install, mini-css-extract-plugin, less-loader

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "web20",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Grunt tasks",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint-nibble WebContent/src/_common/**/*.js WebContent/src/account/**/*.js WebContent/src/advisor/**/*.js WebContent/src/contactUs/**/*.js WebContent/src/csv-ie/**/*.js WebContent/src/fund/**/*.js WebContent/src/intersticeEvents/**/*.js WebContent/src/login/**/*.js WebContent/src/termsAndConditions/**/*.js WebContent/src/userAdmin/**/*.js",
    "test": "karma start",
    "test-chrome": "karma start --no-single-run --browsers Chrome",
    "server-original": "webpack-dev-server --color",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --bail --progress --profile",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --inline --progress --color",
    "start": "npm run server-original",
    "install-artifacts": "npm i && npm shrinkwrap --dev"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.14",
    "angular-animate": "1.4.14",
    "angular-aria": "1.4.14",
    "angular-base64": "2.0.5",
    "angular-cookies": "1.4.14",
    "angular-hotkeys": "1.4.5",
    "angular-resource": "1.4.14",
    "angular-route": "1.4.14",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.4.14",
    "angulartics": "0.19.x",
    "bootstrap": "5.3.0-alpha3",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "jquery": "3.6.4",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "ng-csv": "0.3.6",
    "numeral": "1.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "autoprefixer-loader": "3.2.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "9.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.21.5",
    "clean-css": "5.3.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "6.7.4",
    "eslint-nibble": "8.1.0",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "globule": "1.3.4",
    "html-loader": "4.2.0",
    "html-replace-webpack-plugin": "2.6.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.5.1",
    "isparta-loader": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "karma": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "less": "4.1.3",
    "less-loader": "11.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.7.5",
    "ng-annotate": "1.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "0.10.0",
    "ngannotate-loader": "1.1.0",
    "ngtemplate-loader": "2.1.0",
    "node-dir": "0.1.17",
    "node-libs-browser": "2.2.1",
    "null-loader": "4.0.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "postcss-loader": "7.3.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "4.0.2",
    "rimraf": "5.0.1",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "style-loader": "3.3.3",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "webpack": "5.82.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.15.0"
  }
}
```

webpackconfig.js

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var globule = require('globule');
var CSSExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
var HtmlReplaceWebpackPlugin = require('html-replace-webpack-plugin');
var fs = require('fs');
/**
 * Env
 * Get npm lifecycle event to identify the environment
 */
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || ENV === 'test-watch';
var isProd = ENV === 'build';

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {

    /**
     * Config
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
     * This is the object where all configuration gets set
     */
    var config = {};
    var loginFiles = globule.find([__dirname + "/WebContent/src/login/*.js",
        __dirname + "/WebContent/src/_common/services/shared/*.js", '!' + __dirname + "/WebContent/src/login/login.js"]);
    loginFiles.unshift(__dirname + "/app-login.js");

    var appFiles = globule.find([__dirname + "/WebContent/src/**/*.js", '!' + '!'
    + __dirname + "/WebContent/src/**/!(*spec).js", '!' + __dirname + "/WebContent/src/app.js", '!' + __dirname +
    "/WebContent/src/vendor/**/*", '!' + __dirname + "/WebContent/src/login/*"]);
    appFiles.unshift(__dirname + "/index.js");


    var lessFiles = globule.find([__dirname + "/WebContent/src/_less/*", '!' + __dirname + "/WebContent/src/_less/client.less"]);

    config.entry = isTest ? {} : {
        app: appFiles,
        login: loginFiles,
        less: lessFiles
    };
   // config.debug = true;
    config.output = isTest ? {} : {
        // Absolute output directory
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        // Output path from the view of the page
        // Uses webpack-dev-server in development
        publicPath: isProd ? './' : 'http://localhost:9001/',
        // Filename for entry points
        // Only adds hash in build mode
        filename: isProd ? '[name].[fullhash].js' : '[name].bundle.js',
        // Filename for non-entry points
        // Only adds hash in build mode
        chunkFilename: isProd ? '[name].[fullhash].js' : '[name].bundle.js'
    };

    /**
     * Devtool
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
     * Type of sourcemap to use per build type
     */
    if (isTest) {
        config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
    } else if (isProd) {
        config.devtool = 'source-map';
    } else {
        config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
    }

    config.module = {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {loader:'ngtemplate-loader?relativeTo=/ifastweb20-ui/WebContent/src'},
                    {loader:'html-loader',options: {sources: false}}
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /(node_modules|vendor)/
            },
            // {
            //     test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
            //     loader: 'file-loader?name=vendor/open-sans/[name].[ext]'
            // },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    publicPath: 'images/',
                    outputPath: '_assets/css/images/',
                    name: '[name].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    publicPath: '../../vendor/open-sans/',
                    outputPath: 'vendor/open-sans/',
                    name: '[name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    config.resolve = {
        alias: {
            'spin': 'spin.js', // Workaround a bug in angular-spinner.
            'ng-csv': './node_modules/ng-csv/build/ng-csv.js' // Workaround for badly minified file from vendor creating invalid BOM
        },
         fallback: {
              fs: false,
              "path": false
         }
    };


    config.plugins = [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({}),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ];
    var rules = [];
    var lessFiles = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/WebContent/src/_less');
    var hash = Date.now();
    //we need a loader for each less file as we need separate css files for each client
    lessFiles.forEach(function (file) {
        "use strict";
        var name;
        //css files right now are compiled without the properties namespacing, strip that here
        if (file.indexOf('properties') > -1) {
            name = file.split('properties.less')[0];
        }
        else {
            name = file.split('.less')[0] + '.';
        }

        rules.push(new CSSExtractPlugin({filename: "_assets/css/[name].css"}));

        var loaderName = name + 'properties.less';
        if (file.indexOf('properties') === -1) {
            loaderName = name + 'less';
        }
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: new RegExp(loaderName + '$', 'i'),
            use: [CSSExtractPlugin.loader,'style-loader', 'css-loader','less-loader']
        });
        config.plugins.push(rules[rules.length - 1]);
    });
    config.plugins.push(new HtmlReplaceWebpackPlugin([
        {
            pattern: /_HASH_/g,
            replacement: function() {
                "use strict";
                return hash;
            }
        }
    ]));

    // Skip rendering index.html in test mode
    if (!isTest) {
        // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
        // Render index.html
        config.plugins.push(
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './WebContent/src/index.ejs',
                filename: 'index.html',
                inject: 'head',
                chunks: ['app']
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './WebContent/src/login.ejs',
                filename: 'login.html',
                inject: 'head',
                chunks: ['login']
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './WebContent/src/login_error.ejs',
                filename: 'login_error.html',
                inject: 'head',
                chunks: ['login']
            })
        )
    }
    // Add build specific plugins
    if (isProd) {
        config.plugins.push(
            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
            // Only emit files when there are no errors
            new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),



            // Copy assets from the public folder
            // Reference: https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                {from: __dirname + '/WebContent/src/logout.html', to: 'logout.html'},
                {from: __dirname + '/WebContent/src/404.html', to: '404.html'},
                {from: __dirname + '/WebContent/src/_assets/images', to: '_assets/images'},
                {from: __dirname + '/WebContent/src/vendor', to: 'vendor'} 
            ])
        )
    }

    config.devServer = {
       static: {
              directory: './WebContent/src'
        },
        devMiddleware: {
        stats: 'minimal',
        },
        hot: true,
        port: 9001,
    };
    return config;
}();
```

i am trying to build the application (npm run build). there is no errors. build is successful.

less files are located in web20-ui/WebContent/src/_less/
i am expecting css files to be generated in web20-ui/dist/_assets/css/
But no files generated even though less files are parsed by less loader